# perform varimax rotation in python using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on principal component analysis of a matrix. I have already found the component matrix shown below

```
A = np.array([[-0.73465832 -0.24819766 -0.32045055]
              [-0.3728976   0.58628043 -0.63433607]
              [-0.72617152  0.53812819 -0.22846634]
              [ 0.34042864 -0.08063226 -0.80064174]
              [ 0.8804307   0.17166265  0.04381426]
              [-0.66313032  0.54576874  0.37964986]
              [ 0.286712    0.68305196  0.21769803]
              [ 0.94651412  0.14986739 -0.06825887]
              [ 0.40699665  0.73202276 -0.08462949]])
```

I need to perform varimax rotation in this component matrix but could not find the exact method and degree to rotate. Most of the examples are shown in R. However I need the method in  python.

Comment: +1 good question, I'm also facing same problem..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find a lot of examples with Python. Here is an example I found for Python using only `numpy`, on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Varimax_rotation):

```
def varimax(Phi, gamma = 1, q = 20, tol = 1e-6):
    from numpy import eye, asarray, dot, sum, diag
    from numpy.linalg import svd
    p,k = Phi.shape
    R = eye(k)
    d=0
    for i in xrange(q):
        d_old = d
        Lambda = dot(Phi, R)
        u,s,vh = svd(dot(Phi.T,asarray(Lambda)**3 - (gamma/p) * dot(Lambda, diag(diag(dot(Lambda.T,Lambda))))))
        R = dot(u,vh)
        d = sum(s)
        if d/d_old < tol: break
    return dot(Phi, R)
```

Comment: I believe this should be "gamma = 1.0" in the argument list. Otherwise, the "gamma/p" when calculating the SVD input will be treated as integer division and will result in 0 if p>1 (which it typically is).

Comment: @rmg Unless this is Python 3 or he's using `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia has an example in python [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Varimax_rotation)!

Lifting the example and tailoring it for *numpy*:

```
from numpy import eye, asarray, dot, sum, diag
from numpy.linalg import svd
def varimax(Phi, gamma = 1.0, q = 20, tol = 1e-6):
    p,k = Phi.shape
    R = eye(k)
    d=0
    for i in xrange(q):
        d_old = d
        Lambda = dot(Phi, R)
        u,s,vh = svd(dot(Phi.T,asarray(Lambda)**3 - (gamma/p) * dot(Lambda, diag(diag(dot(Lambda.T,Lambda))))))
        R = dot(u,vh)
        d = sum(s)
        if d_old!=0 and d/d_old < 1 + tol: break
    return dot(Phi, R)
```

Comment: Actually I was looking for using numpy instead of scipy but thanx anyway. i have already looked into that

Comment: @SteveBarnes: `numpy.linalg.svd`.

Comment: @Rajsubit: The import in that example can be (and probably should be) changed to two lines: `from numpy import eye, asarray, dot, sum` and `from numpy.linalg import svd`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Jason added a copy of the example, modified as per Warrens suggestion.

Comment: I got the the rotation as 'extreme' with one variable set to 1 and the rest to values close to zero. I wonder how we can reduce the rotation so that it is more explainable.

Comment: I've read the Kaiser 1958 paper but still find this pretty hard to understand. I got the goal of varimax which is to maximize the (summed) variances of squared loadings. What is this iteration process? Is it Expectation Maximization?

Answer (score 5):

I've looked up solutions for doing factor analysis in python on stack-overflow so many times, that I recently made my own package, [fa-kit](https://github.com/bmcmenamin/fa_kit). Even though this is an old post, I'm throwing up this link in case there's anybody else in the future that gets here via google.

Comment: I like the abbreviation! I see what you did there!