# how to use varimax rotation in python?

Tags: python

I have a varimax rotation code from wikipedia

```
def varimax(Phi, gamma = 1, q = 20, tol = 1e-6):
from numpy import eye, asarray, dot, sum, diag
from numpy.linalg import svd
p,k = Phi.shape
R = eye(k)
d=0
for i in xrange(q):
    d_old = d
    Lambda = dot(Phi, R)
    u,s,vh = svd(dot(Phi.T,asarray(Lambda)**3 - (gamma/p) * dot(Lambda, diag(diag(dot(Lambda.T,Lambda))))))
    R = dot(u,vh)
    d = sum(s)
    if d/d_old < tol: break
return dot(Phi, R)
```

and I use it this way:

```
  varimax(X)  ## X is a numpy array
```

but it returns numbers like this: 2.4243244e-15 !! that's not my expected answer

should I change other arguments? for example gamma or q??
I'm not familiar with varimax rotation

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628589/perform-varimax-rotation-in-python-using-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post an example of what you're using as the inputs for `X` and what kind of outputs you're expecting?

I tested your code by fixing up the indenting in your code, like this:

```
from numpy import eye, asarray, dot, sum, diag
from numpy.linalg import svd

def varimax(Phi, gamma = 1, q = 20, tol = 1e-6):
    p,k = Phi.shape
    R = eye(k)
    d=0
    for i in xrange(q):
        d_old = d
        Lambda = dot(Phi, R)
        u,s,vh = svd(dot(Phi.T,asarray(Lambda)**3 - (gamma/p) * dot(Lambda, diag(diag(dot(Lambda.T,Lambda))))))
        R = dot(u,vh)
        d = sum(s)
        if d/d_old < tol: break
    return dot(Phi, R)
```

And making some dummy components to test it like this:

```
import numpy as np

comps = np.linalg.svd(
    np.random.randn(100,10),
    full_matrices=False
    )[0]

rot_comps = varimax(comps)

print("Original components dimension {}".format(comps.shape))
print("Component norms")
print(np.sum(comps**2, axis=0))

print("Rotated components dimension {}".format(rot_comps.shape))
print("Rotated component norms")
print(np.sum(rot_comps**2, axis=0))
```

The inputs and outputs are 100 x 10 arrays with unit norm, just as you'd expect.

Comment: Also: I've looked up solutions for doing factor analysis in python on stack-overflow so many times, that I recently made my own package (It can't be a good thing that so many people are copy pasting the same mysterious varimax rotation example into their projects...) Anyway, the package lives [here](https://github.com/bmcmenamin/fa_kit) and you can install it as `pip install fa-kit`.